# Invalid Object Name #tablename at second call of #tablename sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

When I execute the code :

```
declare @result int
exec recostcos @result
select @result
```

I get 'Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure RecostCOS, Line 138
Invalid object name '#rLB'.'

The strange thing is The first reference to #rLB did not produce any error but the second reference on line 138 produces the error above.
Please find below the code for recostcos :

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[RecostCOS](@result int output)

as


BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET NOCOUNT ON
--variables
declare @itemName varchar(50)

declare @invoiceNo varchar(50)

declare @customerName varchar(100)

declare @recordedBy varchar(100)

declare @transDate datetime

declare @supCode varchar(50)

declare @decemQty1 decimal(18,6)

declare @decemQty2 decimal(18,6)

declare @decemQty3 decimal(18,6)

declare @recostQty decimal(18,6)

declare @count int

declare @innerCount int

declare @outputCode int

declare @outputCounter int

declare @recId int

declare @innerId int


create table #supcodes(supcode varchar(50),item_name varchar(50),
                       qty decimal(18,6),id int identity(1,1))
create table #recostList(invoice_no varchar(50),qty decimal(18,6), id int identity(1,1))
create table #rLB(invc_no varchar(50),qty decimal(18,6), id int identity(1,1))

--check for supplyCode needing reprocessing
select @count=count(*) from someTable where recosted=0;
if(@count<=0)
 begin
  commit
  set @result=0
  return @result
 end

--
insert into #supcodes(supcode,item_name,qty)
select supply_code,item_name,quantity from someTable
where recosted=0

--recost each supply code needing recosting
while(@count>0)
  begin
    select top 1 @supCode=supcode,@itemName=item_name,@decemQty1=qty,@recId=id
    from #supcodes

    select @decemQty2=sum(current_qty) from someTable2 where item_name=@itemName
    select @decemQty3=quantity from someTable3 where item_name=@itemName
    if(@decemQty2 is null)
      set @decemQty2=0
    if(@decemQty3 is null)
      set @decemQty3=0
    --debug
    if(@decemQty2<>@decemQty3)
       begin
         --check if there is a log of this error
         select @count=count(*) from someTable4 where error_code=1 and 
         item_name=@itemName and supply_code=@supCode and resolved=0

         if(@count<=0)
         --error in stock quantities (this must be resolved b4 any recosting)
         insert into someTable4(supply_code,item_name,error_code,error_source,error_detail)
         values(@supCode,@itemName,1,'re-costing','Mismatch in stock quantities in stock state and supply codes tables') 
       end

    else if(@decemQty1>@decemQty2)
      begin
         --check if there is a log of this error
         select @count=count(*) from someTable4 where error_code=2 and 
         item_name=@itemName and supply_code=@supCode and resolved=0
        --insufficient stock for recosting 
        if(@count<=0)
        insert into someTable4(supply_code,item_name,error_code,error_source,error_detail)
         values(@supCode,@itemName,2,'re-costing','insufficient stock for recosting') 
      end

    else
       begin
         --recost cost of sales of item involved
           --get list of invoices of item to be recosted
           set @recostQty=@decemQty1
           insert into #recostList(invoice_no,qty) 
           select invoice_no,quantity from someTable5
           where supply_code=@supCode and item_name=@itemName

           insert into #rLB(invc_no,qty) select invoice_no,qty from #recostList

           --delete cost of sales relating to supcod and item in stock account
           select @innerCount=count(*) from #recostList
           while(@innerCount>0)
            begin
              select top 1 @invoiceNo=invoice_no,@decemQty2=qty,@innerId=id
              from #recostList

              delete someTable6 where description 
              like 'sales of '+ltrim(rtrim(convert(varchar(20),@decemQty2)))+'%'+
              @itemName+'%'+@invoiceNo

              delete someTable5 where supply_code=@supCode and item_name=@itemName
              and quantity=@decemQty2

              delete #recostList where id=@innerId
              set @innerCount=@innerCount-1
            end 


           --call costByFIFO to recost item
            select @innerCount=count(*) from #rLB
            set @outputCounter=@innerCount
            while(@innerCount>0)
             begin
               select top 1 @invoiceNo=invc_no,@decemQty2=qty,@innerId=id 
               from #rLB

               select @customerName=customer_name, @transDate=trans_date,
               @recordedBy=recorded_by from someTable7 where invoice_no=@invoiceNo

               exec @outputCode=costByFIFO @itemName,@invoiceNo,@customerName,
               @decemQty2,@transDate,@recordedBy

               --ensure each invoice is costed or reverse entire process
               if(@outputCounter=0)
                   begin
                    set @outputCounter=@outputCounter-1
                   end
               else
                  begin
                    set @result=3 --failed to cost all invoices involved
                    rollback
                  end

               delete #rLB where id=@innerId
               set @innerCount=@innerCount-1


             end

            --outputCounter must be 0 to indicate all invoices where costed
            if(@outputCounter<>0) 
               begin
                    set @result=3 --failed to cost all invoices involved
                    rollback
                end
            else
               begin
                 update someTable set recosted=1 where supply_code=@supCode
                 and item_name=@itemName
               end

       end


    delete #supcodes where id=@recId
    set @count=@count-1
  end



SET NOCOUNT OFF

drop table  #supcodes
drop table #recostList
drop table #rLB

set @result=0
COMMIT
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() ErrorNBR, ERROR_SEVERITY() Severity,
   ERROR_LINE () ErrorLine, ERROR_MESSAGE() Msg
   set @result=2 --unexpected error occured
   ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Comment: Where is line 138? We're not going to count that far down...

Comment: Can you post the code for the 'costByFIFO' proc?  Line 138 in your proc is directly on the line where you 'exec' that proc.

Comment: Line 138 is :  delete #rLB where id=@innerId

Comment: I noticed that the editor doesn't give the exact error number so I usually track it manually.

Comment: I resolved the error by modifying my if() else if() else() code to if() else if() else if() structure. Apparently, sql doesn't handle the first structure so well, the last else was confused with if's thereby put the code in line 138 out of scope.